# assigning items of a list to the nodes of a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, graph, power-law

I want to assign items of a list to the nodes of a graph one by one as attributes of those nodes. The code is as follows but it doesn't loop through the second "for". How can I fix this?

```
r = bernoulli.rvs(p=0.4, size=100)
G = nx.Graph(nx.powerlaw_cluster_graph(101, 1, 0.001))
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pol, 'politic')
r_list=r.tolist()

for i in G.nodes():
    for elem in r_list:
        G.nodes[i]['politic'] = elem
```

Comment: Does it throw some error or it just doesn't run?

Comment: It runs without any error. But I've added print statements to find the problem. It shows after selecting the first node it iterates through all of the list items just for one node. Then does the same for the second node and so on. I want to assign one items to one node.

Comment: My code was bugging me, so I changed my answer to a better one, can you check it out if it works, please?

Comment: The last one was correctly worked for me. Except with break not continue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if I get you right, I think you should do this

```py
for i in G.nodes():
    for elem in r_list[:]:
        G.nodes[i]['politic'] = elem
        r_list.remove(elem)
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.